# Can JaCoCo/SonarQube support other unit test framework?

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I just have a couple of questions regarding JaCoCo.

1. Can JaCoCo/SonarQube support other unit test framework?
2. What other unit test framework does it support?
3. Can we turn on/off JaCoCo?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) ask the guys behind JaCoCo or read its documentation 2) ask the guys behind JaCoCO or read its documentation 3) ask the guys behind JaCoCo or read its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Answering on questions 1 and 2: JaCoCo is unit test framework agnostic, i.e. can collect coverage information even in case of manual execution of Java application.

Answering on question 3: simply do not execute JaCoCo.